# Notation of subscript $Hom_{\mathfrak{g}}(A,B)=Hom_{\mathfrak{b}}(C,B)?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra, and let $\mathfrak{b}$ be a Borel subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$.

Let $A,B$ be $\mathfrak{g}$-modules, and $C$ be a $\mathfrak{b}$-module.

What does the subscript mean here: 
$$Hom_{\mathfrak{g}}(A,B)=Hom_{\mathfrak{b}}(C,B)?$$

I guess this means that $\psi:A\to B$ satisfies $\mathfrak{g}\cdot \psi = \psi \cdot \mathfrak{g}$? and the same but for $\mathfrak{b}$ in the image? So $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{b}$ equivariance?

Source, end of page 1: http://www.math.harvard.edu/~gaitsgde/267y/catO.pdf

Comment: = can't be taken literally here, but should probably be interpreted as some natural isomorphism (if you gave the context you'd get a better answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are introducing a Verma module implicitly via an adjunction. To be concrete, suppose $M$ and $N$ are $\mathfrak g$- and $\mathfrak b$-modules, respectively. Because $\mathfrak b$ is a subalgebra of $\mathfrak g$, $M$ can be made into a $\mathfrak b$-module, denote it by $UM$. It then makes sense to consider the hom-set $\hom_{\mathfrak b}(N,UM)$.

Similarly, we can consider the extended $\mathfrak g$-module obtained from $N$ as $U(\mathfrak g)\otimes_{U(\mathfrak b)} N$, denote this by $EN$, and we can consider the hom-set $\hom_{\mathfrak g}(EN,M)$. There is a natural isomorphism
$\hom_{\mathfrak g}(EN,M) \to \hom_{\mathfrak b}(N,UM)$
which the author is considering to be an identification.

Explicitly, this maps a $\mathfrak g$-linear map $f : EN\to M$ to the $\mathfrak b$-linear map $g : N\to UM$ such that $g(n) = f(1\otimes n)$. The inverse assigns a map $g$ to the map $f$ such that $f(a\otimes n) = a g(n)$, and it is readily checked this defines the desired natural isomorphisms.

Comment: This is very clear. Thank you so much. For anyone in the future reading this - look into Frobenius reciprocity - adjointness of the induction and restriction functors.

Comment: One typo almost surely, the Cartan $\mathfrak{h}$ appears on last line of second paragraph, that is meant to be $\mathfrak{b}$ still right?

Comment: @user462339 Yes, sure. ;)

Answer (score 1):

$\operatorname{Hom}_\mathfrak{g}(A,B)$ simply denotes the set of $\mathfrak{g}$-module homomorphisms from $A$ to $B$, and $\operatorname{Hom}_\mathfrak{b}(C,B)$ denotes the set of $\mathfrak{b}$-module homomorphisms from $C$ to $B$. That is, an element $f\in\operatorname{Hom}_\mathfrak{g}(A,B)$ is a linear map $f : A\to B$ such that $f(x\cdot a) = x\cdot f(a)$ for all $x\in\mathfrak{g}$, $a\in A$.

The subscript tells you which Lie algebra you are considering the arguments as modules over: if $\mathfrak{b}$ and $\mathfrak{g}$ are both relevant in some application or topic, then writing simply $\operatorname{Hom}(A,B)$ (for $\mathfrak{g}$-modules $A$ and $B$) might be ambiguous. After all, $A$ and $B$ can be thought of as either $\mathfrak{g}$-modules OR as $\mathfrak{b}$-modules via restriction of scalars.

Comment: For my equality of Hom's to even make sense, I suppose I must have that $C\subset A$ or $A\subset C$. But if we are only requiring $\mathfrak{b}$-equivariance in the latter, I am safe to assume that $C\subset A$?

Then does this equality tell me that every homomorphism $A\to B$ factors through by composition $A\to C\to B$?

Comment: If you want the two sets to be literally equal, you would need $C = A$. However, it's more likely a natural isomorphism of some sort (i.e., the hom-sets are in a bijection which is functorial in both slots). To say more it would be helpful for you to provide more context, or at least say what text you're finding this statement in (and where it is in the text).

Comment: Please see the end of page 1 of :

http://www.math.harvard.edu/~gaitsgde/267y/catO.pdf